# laravel file upload if php fileinfo extension not alowed and cant't allow on shared server

Tags: php, laravel, image, upload, intervention

I often have a problem with servers which I am using. They don't allow php fileinfo extension and it's impossible to allow it.

Can anybody tell me good alternative Intervention Image to upload image and resize in Laravel?
or using Intervention Image without  fileinfo extension?

Comment: Hmm. This seems hard. Afaik, if you want to MIME check an upload, you simply need that extension. You can always return to using a combination of `pathinfo` and the GD extension, but I wonder whether that's enabled if fileinfo isn't. The grunty developer solution is to switch hosting providers, since the fileinfo extension has been enabled by default since PHP 5.3.

Comment: I can't switch hosting provider. and php version on server is 5.6 but fileinfo extension is not enabled and they don't want to enable it

Comment: Then I'm 99% sure you're out of luck and have to write custom code to do what Intervention normally would. If GD extension is enabled, that custom isn't very extensive.